# How to learn internals of the Go Programming Language?

Tags: go

Recently I've participated several Go job interviews. The first one asked me `How is channel implemented?`, then the second one asked `How is goroutine implemented?`. Well as you can guess, the next one asked `How is a Go interface implemented?`.

I've been using Go for six months, but to be honest I never did care or know these `Go internals`.

I tried to learn these by reading the source code of Go, but can't really understand the quintessence.

So the question is, for a noob in Go, how do I learn the Go internals?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/teh-cmc/go-internals

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, I've been there, but I mean is there any lower level docs or tutorials?

Comment: If I get questions like that in an interview, it tells me I don't want to work there, because they're asking (mostly) irrelevant questions.  If, on the other hand, they ask "How would you implement channels?", that's useful, because it explores _your_ thought process, not your ability to regurgitate memorized information.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The most organized collection of internal resources links is probably this:

[**Golang Internals Resources**](https://github.com/emluque/golang-internals-resources)

Other than that, answers to these questions aren't collected in once place, but they are scattered in different blog posts.

Slice internals: [The Go Blog: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

String internals: [The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

Constants internals: [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)

Reflection insight: [The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Interface internals: [RSC: Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Channel implementation: Overview on SO: [How are Go channels implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621149/how-are-go-channels-implemented)

Channel internals: [Go channel on steroids](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yIAYmbvL3JxOKOjuCyon7JhW4cSv1wy5hC0ApeGMV9s/pub)

Map implementation: Overview on SO: [Golang map internal implementation - how does it search the map for a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995648/golang-map-internal-implementation-how-does-it-search-the-map-for-a-key); also related: [Go's maps under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290522/gos-maps-under-the-hood/59292254#59292254)

Map internals: [Macro View of Map Internals In Go](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/12/macro-view-of-map-internals-in-go.html)

Answer (score 20):

Let me warn you that you *may be* missing the real point of the interviewers.

(Disclaimer: I do job interviews of Go programmers from time to time,
for a somewhat demanding project, so all of the below is my personal
world view. Still, it is shared by my cow-orkers ;-)).

Most of the time, it's rather worthless for an employee to know precisely how this or that bit of the runtime (or the compiler) is implemented—in part because this may change in any future release, and in part because there
do exist at least two up-to-date implementations of Go ("the gc suite", and
a part of GCC), and they all are free to implement a particular feature
in any way they wish.

What a (sensible) interviewer *should* really be interested in is
whether you understand "the why" of a particular core feature.

Say, when they ask you to explain how a channel is implemented,
what they *should* be interested to hear from you is that a channel
provides synchronization and may also provide buffering.
So you may tell them that a channel *is like*
a variable protected by a mutex—for the case of an unbuffered channel,—or
like a slice protected by a mutex.
And then add that an upshot of using a channel instead of a hand-crafted
solution involving a mutex is that operations on channels
can be easily combined using the `select` statement, while implementing
a matching functionality without channels is possible (and by that time
they will probably would like to hear from you about `sync.Cond`)
but is really cumbersome and error-prone.

It's not actually *completely* worthless to know nitty-gritty details
of channels—say to know that their implementation tries hard to lower
the price paid for the synchronization in the "happy case"
(there is no contention at the
moment a goroutine accesses a channel), and that it is also clever about
not jumping straight into the kernel to sleep on a lock in the
"unhappy case", but I see no point in knowng these details by heart.

The same applies to goroutines. You should maintain a clear picture in what
are the differences between an OS process and a thread running in it,
and what *context* belongs to a thread—that is, what is needed to be saved
and restored when switching between the threads.
And then the differences between an OS thread and a "green thread" which
a goroutine mostly is. It's okay to just know who schedules OS threads
and who schedules goroutines, and why the latter is faster.
And what are the benefits of having goroutines (the main one is network
poller integrated into the scheduler (see [this](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/)),
the second is dynamic stacks, the third is low context switching overhead
most of the time).

My recommendation is to read through the list presented by @icza.

And in addition to what you've asked about,
I'd present the following list of what a good candidate
should be familiar with—in the order from easiest to hardest (to grok):

- The mechanics of slices and `append`. You should know arrays exist
  and how they are different from slices.
- How interfaces are implemented.
- The dualistic nature of Go strings (given `s` contains a string,
  what is the difference between iterating over its contents via
  `for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ { c := s[i] }` over `for i, c := range s {}`).

  Also: what kinds of data strings may contain—you should know that it's
  perfectly okay to contain arbitrary binary data in them, UTF-8 is not
  a requirement.

  The differences between `string` and `[]byte`.
- How blocking I/O is implemented (for the network; that's about
  the netpoller integrated into the runtime).

  Knowing about the difference in handing non-network blocking I/O and
  syscalls in general is a bonus.
- How the scheduler is implemented (those `P`s running `G`s on `M`s).

Comment: Well said. I've been an interviewer in the past (for Java), and when asking internal-related questions, I was never after whether the candidate knew the actual details but more after his general knowledge and understanding of the context.

Comment: Is _"cow-orkers"_ a typo or intended in your answer?

Comment: @icza, that's an american joke (I learned in the [tcl community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl)) :-)

Comment: Well explained, but there is still a question haunting me, that is go was designed to be simple, to keep the complexity hidden behind simplicity, therefore increases readability. So what exactly can we achieve by knowing the internals?  By that, I mean one can use goroutine and channels to build an application without even knowing the concept of thread and coroutine.

Comment: @FrontMage Go was designed to be simple, which also means it has relatively few features compared to other languages. By knowing the internals you gain skill and knowledge to better craft the features you're in need of but are not provided by Go; or maybe achieve what you want with what Go _does_ provide, using the features more optimally, potentially for things they were not meant in the first place. For example, channels were designed for safe communication between goroutines, yet they can be used for a simple and safe [memory pool of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38506367/1705598).

Comment: «By that, I mean one can use goroutine and channels to build an application without even knowing the concept of thread and coroutine.» this is simply not true. You can't do that without knowing *the concepts* of them. It may well be that you actually wanted to say "…without knowing the details of their implementation". Then yes, that would be true, but then it's what @icza said…

Comment: …but then note that Go strikes a good balance between being reasonably high-level and—at the same time— *close to the metal.* This latter property allows for two things. 1) Performance problems can be sanely assessed and analyzed (and Go has good tools to do that). But such analysis may require knowledge of how things work. 2) Knowing how things work allows you to think about ways of optimizing your algorythms, when and where it's needed.

Answer (score 5):

This GitHub repo would be helpful to get to know about go internals.

You can get all go-internals related resources here.

[A collection of articles and videos to understand Golang internals.](https://github.com/emluque/golang-internals-resources)

[image]

[A book about the internals of the Go programming language](https://github.com/teh-cmc/go-internals)

[image]